# AngularJS ngRepeat element removal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

There are quite a few questions on how to implement item removal inside ngRepeat directive, and as I figured out, it comes down to using **ngClick** and triggering some remove function passing it item's **$index**.

However, I couldn't find anywhere an example where I have multiple ngRepeats:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="email in user.emails">
        {{ email }} <a href>Remove</a>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="phone in user.phones">
        {{ phone }} <a href>Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

For this, I would need to create **$scope.removePhone** and **$scope.removeEmail** which would be called using **ngClick** on *Remove anchor*. But I'm looking for a more generic solution. Especially since I have many pages with **many ngRepeats** .

I was thinking about writing a directive which would be placed on **Remove anchor** and would do something like this:

1. Find **ngRepeat** among parent elements.
2. Read what it's iterating over ('user.emails' in first case, 'user.phones' in second)
3. Remove **$index** element from **THAT** model.

So the markup would look something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="email in user.emails">
        {{ email }} <a href remove-directive="$index">Remove</a>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="phone in user.phones">
        {{ phone }} <a href remove-directive="$index">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is what I'm looking for possible to achieve and what would be the preferred way to do this?

#### Current hacky solution

Here is how I do it currently. It's hacky and ugly but gets the job done until I figure out a prettier way.

```
  myAppModule.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $parse, $routeParams, User) {
    $scope.user = User.get({id: $routeParams.id});

    $scope.remove = function ($index, $event) {
      // TODO: Find a way to make a directive that does this. This is ugly. And probably very wrong.
      var repeatExpr = $($event.currentTarget).closest('[ng-repeat]').attr('ng-repeat');
      var modelPath  = $parse(repeatExpr.split('in')[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));

      $scope.$eval(modelPath).splice($index, 1);
    };
  });
```

And in DOM:

```
<div ng-repeat="email in user.email" class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">
    {{ "Email Address"|_trans }}
  </label>

  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" ng-model="email.address">

    <span class="help-inline"><a href ng-click="remove($index, $event)">{{ "Delete"|_trans }}</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "No JS" is the best answer. (in case you just look at the one w/ the most up-votes)

Answer (score 79):

You could create a generic remove method that would take in the array and the item to remove.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="email in emails">{{ email }} <a ng-click="remove(emails, $index)">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones">{{ phone }} <a ng-click="remove(phones, $index)">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>

$scope.remove = function(array, index){
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: While this works and did cross my mind, it still requires me to repeat myself (which is a bad thing in programming as far as I know :-) ): I already specified I'm iterating through mails, I would like to "skip" part where I have to redefine that ('emails' argument in method call). I would like to be left with **remove(email)**

Comment: Not repeating yourself is ideal, however keeping things simple is also very important.

Comment: You are not repeating yourself, you are calling a function multiple times at different location with different parameters. End of the day you need to get the app build and hence should be pragmatic ;)

Comment: Maybe off topic, but how can an object get deleted from ng-repeat when it's not an array?

Not sure how to pass in the right object to delete from the view.

Comment: Anyone notice a delay when using this? Seems like it takes a few seconds to remove the item from the object/array.

Comment: @allencoded Yes, it does, because of `ngAnimate`. Once it's removed, Angular puts a `ng-leave` class to it, waits about 0.2s and removes it from the DOM. Just use CSS classes to remove that element however you want.

Comment: The "No JS" answer is actually better and should be upvoted/accepted.

Answer (score 72):

### No JS

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options" ng-init=options=[1,2,3,4,5]>
   <button ng-click="options.splice($index,1)">Remove me</button>      
</div>
```

Comment: simplest, easiest, and best use of angular

Comment: Excellent job, this is exactly what I was looking for.   Concise with no garbage.

Comment: Ummm... there is javascript. I think you mean "No *external* JS"

Answer (score 19):

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="email in emails as datasource">{{ email }} 
        <a ng-click="datasource.splice($index,1)">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones as datasource">{{ phone }} 
        <a ng-click="datasource.splice($index,1)">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. if you are removing an item with no validation, no soft delete ( removing from the list but keeping in memory) you this is very elegant. you can always wrap this as a method if you want tot keep "code" out of your html declarations.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple and convenient way that works cross-browser is to use the 'remove' utility method from the library lodash.

```
<div ng-repeat="phone in phones">{{ phone }} 
  <a ng-click="removeItem(phones, phone)">Remove</a>
</div>
```

In your controller you declare then

```
//inject lodash dependency

//declare method in scope
$scope.removeItem = function(list, item){
   lodash.remove(list,function(someItem) { return item === someItem});
}
```

You may of course use indexes if you like. See https://lodash.com/docs#remove

Comment: I know this is really old, but worth calling out that this answer is using  the specific ng-lodash implementation of lodash: https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash

Answer (score 1):

If you have used ng-repeat on an object instead of an array, do the following.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="email in emails">{{ email }} 
      <a ng-click="remove(emails, email)">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones">{{ phone }} 
      <a ng-click="remove(phones, phone)">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>

$scope.remove = function(objects, o){
    delete object[o.id];
}
```

or the more terse

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="email in emails">{{ email }} 
      <a ng-click="delete emails[email.id]">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones">{{ phone }} 
      <a ng-click="delete phones[phone.id]">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

presumes that the objects look like this

```
var emails = {  '123' : { id : '123', .... }  };

var phones = {  '123' : { id : '123', .... }  };
```