# Delete multiple ng-repeat elements on click of a single button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table showing project names as shown in below image ,

[image]

On delete button click, I am passing the selected check-boxes data as array of objects to my controller

```
[{id:1,name:'Name 8'},{id:2,name:'Name 7'}]
```

Then deleting the names from the table at the server side. This all works fine but how do i remove the rows from DOM after deleting them?? I went through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251814/angularjs-ngrepeat-element-removal) which says how to remove ng-repeat elemets from DOM but in that case the elements are removed one at a time, by passing the $index to the splice() function

In my case i need to remove multiple rows. If ill have to use the splice function in my controller how do i get the index from the selected rows object? Or is there any better way of doing it.

Hope my question is clear!

**Update:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCC36/6/)

Solution: Well i had to modify @wickY26 answer a bit to suite my scenario. Here is my update [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCC36/7/)

What i did was , in the delete() change code to

```
angular.forEach($scope.projects, function (row, index) {
            if($scope.projects[index].checked) {
                $scope.projects.splice(index,1);
            }            
        });
```

Comment: you're ng-repeat is binded to a scope array/object ? Just splice it from this array and the angular dual-binding will remove the lines itself.. or am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes i am passing array of objects of selected check boxes like - [{id:1,name:'Name 8'},{id:2,name:'Name 7'}]

Comment: Please create a fiddle/plunkr. I guess you need to add `$scope.apply()` at the end of your delete event listener.

Comment: @Alp - I have updated my question with jsFiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep selected rows on an object via binding `checkbox` with ng-model,
so example table html should be like this

**HTML**

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data" ng-class="{'success' : tableSelection[$index]}">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tableSelection[$index]" />
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
          {{cell}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and if you define a function in your controller which travel through your data and splice array depends on **tableSelection** object boolean values...

**UPDATE**

after your comment I debug my code and see I cannot remove multiple rows same time, so I look at my code and change some part of it...

at my example you cannot **delete multiple rows same time** because everytime you **splice** an element from `data` array you **shift indexes of array** for rest, so right way to do it starting from **last index**,

Here new **CONTROLLER**

```
  $scope.removeSelectedRows = function() {
    //start from last index because starting from first index cause shifting
    //in the array because of array.splice()
    for (var i = $scope.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if ($scope.tableSelection[i]) {
        //delete row from data
        $scope.data.splice(i, 1);
        //delete rowSelection property
        delete $scope.tableSelection[i];
      }
    }
  };
```

I update my [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJq0Qy3j5nGr1eJ9f9QA?p=preview) added comments and some other functionallty as well...

Comment: Your solution works but my scenario is different here, i need a universal checkbox that will select disselect all. Please check my jffiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LCC36/6/

Comment: You may have just saved my job hahaha Thank you