# Delete multiple ng-repeat rows not working using datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

After implementing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527655/delete-multiple-ng-repeat-elements-on-click-of-a-single-button), i soon implemented it with jquery datatables. But its not working like expected.

When i try to delete rows its not deleting , and if i click on next and come back, the deleted rows reappear.

Here is my [jsFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/LCC36/10/)

The code below is not behaving as expected:

```
angular.forEach($scope.projects, function (row, index) {
            if($scope.projects[index].checked) {
                $scope.projects.splice(index,1);
            }            
        });
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you abandon trying to get jquery datatables working with angular.
Instead you should use this: http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-table